# Magento + Varnish + Turpentine and the cart doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello i'm using Magento 1.9.1 and i'm tring to migrate my e-commerce web site into a new web server.

The web server is using Varnish 4.0 and and i have install in my Magento Turpentine 0.7.1

The web site with Turpentine and Varnish active goes well except the cart.
Infact the cart shows products that have been added by different users in different pc.

Can you help me understand why this happens and what kind of modification i have to do to Varnish or Magento or Turpentine?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you have full page cache enabled please ensure you're excluding dynamic content blocks such as cart, basket and checkout etc. Or else it will server the cached version to everyone effectively making your site non-transactional

Comment: My turpentine is configured in this way https://postimg.org/image/6ozqj26rb/ what i have done is disable ESI block, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, your full page cache settings for the actual module within system configuration should allow you to exempt certain parts of the site from FPC. Please consult your module providers manual on how to do this

Comment: OK Timothy i understand i will ask to my provider and will let you know, thank you very much